# Overwrite Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides, catalogsearch

I know, it's been asked a lot but it just doesn't work for me.

my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyModule_CatalogSearch>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </MyModule_CatalogSearch>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <blocks>
      <MyModule_CatalogSearch>
        <class>MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block</class>
      </MyModule_CatalogSearch>
      <catalogsearch>
        <rewrite>
            <advanced_form>
                MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form
            </advanced_form>
        </rewrite>
      </catalogsearch>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

and in local/MyModule/CatalogSearch/Block/Advanced I got Form.php

```
<?php
class MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // add Home breadcrumb
        if ($breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
            $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', array(
                'label'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('Home'),
                'title'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('Go to Home Page'),
                'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()
            ))->addCrumb('search', array(
                'label'=>Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->__('MyCatalogSearch')
            ));
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

     public function getStoreCategories()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        return $helper->getStoreCategories();
    }
}
```

In exception.log I get the following:
Invalid block type2:

```
                MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form
            #0 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage->throwException('Invalid block type2: 
                MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form
            ')
#1 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalogsearch/advanced_form', Array)
#2 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form', 'catalogsearch_advanced_form')
#3 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form', 'catalogsearch_advanced_form')
#4 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element, Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)
#5 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)
#6 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 //app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/AdvancedController.php(39): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_AdvancedController->indexAction()
#10 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 //app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)
#12 //app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 //app/Mage.php(675): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /4/magento/index.php(87): Mage->run('', 'store')
```

I changed Layout.php to see where there exception is thrown and it happens in

```
if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block type2: %s', $block));
        }
```

Can someone explain WHY this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Solution: There were spaces before the class name. Removing them as suggested by Amit solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<MyModule_CatalogSearch>
<class>MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block</class>
</MyModule_CatalogSearch>
```

change to

```
<mymodulecatalogsearch>
<class>MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block</class>
</mymodulecatalogsearch>
```

Explain:

here `<MyModule_CatalogSearch>` is a `block type`and it is `always be lower letters`.

Block type is `always be  small letter`.As we define  block type is `<mymodulecatalogsearch> then it class MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block`

config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyModule_CatalogSearch>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </MyModule_CatalogSearch>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <blocks>
     <mymodulecatalogsearch>
        <class>MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block</class>
    </mymodulecatalogsearch>
      <catalogsearch>
        <rewrite>
            <advanced_form>MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form</advanced_form>
        </rewrite>
      </catalogsearch>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I changed it but the same exception is still being thrown. On a cms block I'm adding a block using {{block type="MyModule_CatalogSearch/block" name="filter_result" }} which happens to work just fine

Comment: {{block type="mymodulecatalogsearch/block" name="filter_result" }}   AS mymodulecatalogsearch  as block type  of module MyModule_CatalogSearch

Comment: im sure this would work as well but this didn't fix my actual problem

Comment: which problem ?

Comment: that the exception is being thrown i described in my original post when I call /catalogsearch/advanced. In my comment I just wanted to say that adding a block on a category page using this name works fine.

Comment: for checking rewrite the echo get_class $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form'); check rewrite class is MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form or not

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand. Where can I check this? I was assuming that exception being thrown already means that the original file is being overridden.

Comment: ok ,i will check

Comment: there issue with <advanced_form>MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form</advanced_form> some space between <advanced_form></advanced_form>

Comment: on header.phtml put this <?php echo get_class $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_form'); ?> for checking your block class of block type(catalogsearch/advanced_form)  is  MyModule_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed all the spaces between advanced form and now it finally works!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your file in which you've got the class:

```
Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form
```

You might have an accidental change in it. Check to see if the above class inherits from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract or on of it's child classes.

Comment: I posted the file in my original Post. It inherits from Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form,

Comment: Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form should inherit from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract or one of it's child classes. Check that.